# Running Stored Procedure from Matlab Only Returns 1 row

Tags: mysql, matlab, mysql-workbench

I am retrieving data from a mysql database in matlab.

```
conn=database('my_database','','');
sql = 'call latest_hl_tradables()';
curs = exec(conn,sql);   
curs = fetch(curs);
```

Yesterday, the code returned 600 rows.  This morning, it returns 1 row.  If I run the stored procedure (latest_hl_tradables) in MySQL Workbench, it still returns 600 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, it the code started working again.

All I did was write some diagnostic code to count the number of records in the tables that latest_hl_tradables() queries.  Initially those only returned 1 row.  Then when they started returning all the rows.  I don't know what changed.

Answer (score 0):

(My configuration is R2014b / SQL Server 2014 / MS JDBC 4.0. I believe the OP describes a generic issue, not database-vendor-specific)

I have also experienced unreliable results within MATLAB from stored procedures which return result sets. I submitted a service request to Mathworks. The short answer is that in this use case, neither of the Matlab Database Toolbox functions exec or runstoredprocedure are appropriate. Rather, stored procedures should be called from MATLAB via [runsqlscript](http://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/runsqlscript.html). Here's the tech's response:

> Unfortunately there is no way to get output of the query using the
>       cursor object.  The only way to get the output on DML is by running
>       them as a script. The syntax is:
>
> ```
>     >>results = runsqlscript(connObject,'ScriptName.sql')
>
> where the SQL queries are placed in the file "ScriptName.sql". 
> This will return cell array of results as the output
> ```

Note that this solution makes life complicated when your stored procedure requires input parameters. In typical cases when sp parameters aren't known a priori, this means you have to generate a custom SQL script on-the-fly & write it out to disk.